# Modernizr getusermedia undefined

Tags: webrtc, modernizr, getusermedia

I am confused why

`Modernizr.getusermedia`

is undefined, but when I type in

`!!navigator.webkitGetUserMedia`

it returns true. I am using Chrome and I know webrtc is supported... so why does Modernizr say its undefined.

The Modernizr that I downloaded with bower has the getusermedia.js file in it with the line:

`Modernizr.addTest('getusermedia', !!Modernizr.prefixed('getUserMedia', navigator));`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getUserMedia` isn't a core test in Modernizr so it is not included by default.
When you setup your own download on the Modernizr website you can select it to include it but Bower loads the default.
Bower just clones the Git repo to you local machine so when you want none core tests you'll have to do some extra work.

To add that test also include the file `feature-detects/webrtc/getusermedia.js` in your page or add the contents of that script to another script on the page.

Comment: Ahh, I thought that may be the issue, I just saw the file in there and assumed they included it... guess I'm not using bower for Modernizr anymore.